# How to make a line of text in a slightly different color (light gray in my case) in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color, emphasis

I Like to add an informal footnote to my document, containing web addresses. Some of the text is to be de-emphasized using gray text.

How do I do that for a line or a word in XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use regular `xcolor` and `hyperref` methods for colouring elements.  Here's an example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor={black!40}}
\newcommand{\deemph}[1]{{\color{black!40}#1}}
\begin{document}
This is some text and \deemph{this is some deemphasized text}.

This is a grey link: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX Stack Exchange}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, works best. For my needs, using `\code{gray}` and `\code{lightgray}` is sufficient, though.